# Powershell internetexplorer.application not updating innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, internet-explorer

I am trying to get some information from my TP-Link Router webpage.

I succeeded in logging in. But after I'm logged in, I tried to print the innerhtml and it shows the same one from the login page. The thing is when I press login, I get redirected to a other index-page. I tried the navigate2 function to go to this index-page. Sadly I just get logged off and shown the login page.

My code is:

```
# Create instance of InternetExplorer
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$username = "XXXXXXX"
$password = "XXXXXXX"
$ie.Navigate2("http://192.168.0.1")

while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep 1}

# load JQuery
$ie.Document.body.innerHTML = $ie.Document.body.innerHTML + "<div id=`"a`" onclick=`"var th = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];var s = document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');s.setAttribute('src','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');th.appendChild(s);`">hello</div>"

Write-Host $ie.Document.body.innerHTML

# This works - login sequence
$UserNameField = $ie.Document.getElementById('userName')
$UserNameField.value = "$username"
$PassField = $ie.Document.getElementById('pcPassword')
$PassField.value = "$password"

$ie.Document.getElementById("loginBtn").click()

#This output is the same as the previous one. But if I inspect the page it is different html.
Write-Host $ie.Document.body.innerHTML
```

Is there any way to keep the HTML-data up to date, the way you would 'inspect' your browser?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Hey sure, it is nothing special: https://pastebin.com/a7D3jEWY.